# How to get java ArrayList values into Datgrid in flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

In my Sample Application(java+Flex) Java class method like..

```
public class Sample
{

public ArrayList method1()
{
ArrayList al =new ArrayList();
al.add("one");
al.add("TWO");
}
```

And in Flex side connect the Blazeds connections... all are done Perfectly and My `MXML file code` is

```
          public var userService:Sample = new Sample();
            protected function init_Call(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var rpcSearchResult:AsyncToken = userService.method1();
                rpcSearchResult.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(success, failure));
            }
            [Bindable]public var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            public function success(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                ac=event.result as ArrayCollection;
                Alert.show("Result : "+ac.getItemAt(0,0));

            }
            public function failure(event:FaultEvent):void
            {

                Alert.show("This is Fault Event");
            }
```

...
...

```
<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" left="12" right="12" top="49" bottom="54" horizontalCenter="0"
                requestedRowCount="4" verticalCenter="-3" dataProvider="{ac}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
        <s:GridColumn dataField="one" headerText="FirstValue"></s:GridColumn>
        <s:GridColumn dataField="two" headerText="SecondValue"></s:GridColumn>

        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>

</s:DataGrid>
```

But I don't get any value on DataGrid but ResultEvent function Alert show 'one','two' values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem may be in the variable that you assign to **Datagrid**. Try set "**ac**" as **[BINDABLE]** or replace your function success for this following:

```
public function success(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            datagrid.dataProvider = event.result;
        }
```

I hope it will be helpful.